# how do i determine what is causing a "java.SQLException no table used" error and solve it

Tags: java, mysql

I am recieving an exception after executing a query to select from a table in java. The query runs properly in mySQL but when its used in java i'll get the exception. I tried running the exact same query in mySQL and it runs fine but it'll give an exception on java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eldenringbuildgenerator" , "root", "admin");
            Statement teststmt = Con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = teststmt.executeQuery("select * ;"); // test query to make sure connection is real
            rs = teststmt.executeQuery("select ArmorTypeID,ArmorTypeName from armortypes;");
            // will delete later
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " );
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }
```

Comment: ResultSet rs = teststmt.executeQuery("select * ;"); // test query to make sure connection is real

this is incorrect format. instead you use this             ResultSet rs = teststmt.executeQuery("select 1 ;"); // test query to make sure connection is real
to make sure connecting is working.

Comment: thank you i forgot i had that there

Comment: So: change `"select * ;"` to `"select 1"`.

Comment: @andrewJames That's an interesting one. I never thought of doing bare  `select *` before so in 20+ years of sql never ran  into this

Answer (score 0):

To wrap up the solution from the comments, and add a little bit of information, in the hope it would be of use for others getting here.

The solution is replacing `"select *;"` by `"select 1"`, the exception is thrown because JDBC cannot determine the columns from the former SQL query.